# How to transform for loop with asynchronous operation inside

Tags: javascript

I've a scenario where I've a variable number of grids in a page and when the user click a button I need to do the following:

For each grid

1. Get some data from the grids
2. Show a dialog box to write some data
3. Do a $.post() operation after the dialog box is closed
4. Process the next grid

Here's a code snippet of what I'm doing

```
for (var i = 0; i < grids.length; i++) {
  var grid = grids[i];

  // Process some grid's data
    ...

  // Show a dialog box to write some extra data
    dialog.open(); // dialog is a Telerik Window widget

  // When the dialog box is closed do a $.post()
    $.post(...)
      .fail(function(error) {

      })
      .done(function(data) {

      });
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that the dialog box open in asynchronous way (I'm using Telerik Window widget for the dialog) so I need to transform the *for* loop to make the process synchronous.

Can anyone please tell me how to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: Does `dialog.open` return any sort of promise?

Comment: No, but here they show how to create a dialog **via Promises** http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/layout/window/how-to/confirmation-dialog-promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just `shift` from an array in a function:

```
var grids = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
];

function doSomething() {
    if (grids.length) {
        var grid = grids.shift();

        //use setTimeout as a means of async
        setTimeout(function() {
            //do something
            console.log(grid);

            if (grids.length) {
                doSomething();
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}

doSomething();
```